# Explain plan hint details as plain text

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan, hint, oracle18c

I'm trying to learn how to force Oracle 18c to use a function-based index — by using a **hint**:

```
--I've omitted the custom function and function-based index because it cluttered the question too much.
--https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431019/62572

with cte as (
    select  /*+ INDEX (active_transportation atn_endpoint_list_idx) */
         infrastr.endpoint_list(shape) as list
    from
        infrastr.active_transportation
    where
        infrastr.endpoint_list(shape) is not null
    )    
select
    to_char(rownum) || '-STARTPOINT' as unique_id,
    cast(regexp_substr(list, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as number) as x,
    cast(regexp_substr(list, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as number) as y
from
    cte  
union all
select
    to_char(rownum) || '-ENDPOINT' as unique_id,
    cast(regexp_substr(list, '[^,]+', 1, 3) as number) as x,
    cast(regexp_substr(list, '[^,]+', 1, 4) as number) as y
from
    cte
```

---

When I hit the explain plan button in SQL Developer, I get this:

[image]

And I can see that there is information about hints. Good.

---

Similarly, I want to output the explain plan as plain text, using:

```
explain plan for
...(the query)

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
```

But when I do that, I don't see any details about the hint:

```
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                             | 29068 |   110M|    77   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D669A_67C8FF97 |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN                       | ATN_ENDPOINT_LIST_IDX       | 14534 |   965K|   161   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   UNION-ALL                              |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |    COUNT                                 |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |     VIEW                                 |                             | 14534 |    27M|    38   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D669A_67C8FF97 | 14534 |   965K|    38   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |    COUNT                                 |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |     VIEW                                 |                             | 14534 |    27M|    38   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D669A_67C8FF97 | 14534 |   965K|    38   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - filter("INFRASTR"."ENDPOINT_LIST"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL)
```

---

Question:

How can I output the explain plan as plain text — and include details about hint usage?

I tried using a line from this page: [Oracle Scratchpad - Fussy FBIs](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/category/oracle/indexing/function-based-indexes/#:%7E:text=cost%20allstats%20last%20hint_report%20remote%20outline):

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'cost allstats last hint_report remote outline'));
```

But I got an error:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-----------------
Error: format 'cost allstats last hint_report remote outline' not valid for DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be after the outline, ie

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from emp;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'+outline'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    11 |   407 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    11 |   407 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      FULL(@"SEL$1" "EMP"@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      ALL_ROWS
      DB_VERSION('19.1.0')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

40 rows selected.
```